# Can a creep commit suicide?

Tags: screeps

I am programming a script for my guards, if the guard can't move, make the guard commit suicide, so my system can spawn a new one again.

But how do I do that? It's not listed in the docs.
I am looking for something like this:

```
creep.commitSuicide();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New method [`Creep.suicide()`](https://docs.screeps.com/api/#Creep.suicide) has been added to the API today ([changelog](http://screeps.com/docs/changelog.php)).

Comment: Does this make it drop energy too?

Comment: Yes it does, the behavior is the same as when it's killed.

Answer (score 1):

```
creep = null;
```

This will make the creep "commit suicide" and dropping all it's energy.